# stopping my function on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/

here I can add and remove unlimited inputs on my page.

My question is how can I make this function to produce maximum 6 more inputs then hiding the "Add Another Input Box" link.

I am a newbie. This question must be really easy for javascript programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/38RE6/7/

This implements what everyone else suggested - check the `i` counter variable, and hide the link when necessary. Note that you had an error in your code - you can't add multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, so I had to change `id="remScnt"` to `class="remScnt"` and change the corresponding selector.

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: @liho1eye - agreed - but maybe a commented code sample and an explanation of what needed to be changed is somewhere in between?

Answer (score 2):

After incrementing `i`, you want to check `if (i >= 6)` and `.hide()` the add link.

You probably want to `.show()` it again whenever you remove an input.  (if it's already visible, `.show()` won't do anything).

Answer (score 0):

You already keeping track of the input count in your `i` variable. What stops you from just adding `if(i>=6)return false;` first thing in your click handler?